# Use Regex to parse out some part of URL using python

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7, python-3.x

Suppose I am having some like as the following,

```
URL
http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=fa+gw+hw+ek+ei/
http://hostname.com/wqs/ck$st=fasd+/
http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=fa+gq+hf+kg+is&sadfnlslkdfn&gl+jh+ke+oj+kp sfav
```

I want to check for first + symbol in the url and move backward until we find a special character such as / or ? or = or any other special character and start from that and go on until we find a space or end of line or & or /.

The regex which I wrote with the help of stackoverflow forums is as follows,

```
re.search(r"[^\w\+ ]([\w\+ ]+\+[\w\+ ]+)(?:[^\w\+ ]|$)", x).group(1)
```

This one works with the first row. But does not parse anything with second row. Also in the third row,  I want to check for multiple patterns like this in the row. The current regex checks only for one pattern.

My output should be,

```
parsed
fa+gw+hw+ek+ei
fasd
fa+gq+hf+kg+is gl+jh+ke+oj+kp
```

Can anybody help me to modify the regex which is already there to suit this needs?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used regexr to come up with this ([regexr link](http://regexr.com/3e3go)):

`([\w\+]*\+[\w\+]*)(?:[^\w\+]|$)`

Matches:

`fa+gw+hw+ek+ei
fasd+
fa+gq+hf+kg+is
gl+jh+ke+oj+kp`

EDIT: Instead of using re.search, try using re.findall instead:

```
>>> s = "http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=fa+gq+hf+kg+is&sadfnlslkdfn&gl+jh+ke+oj+kp sfav"
>>> re.findall("([\w\+]+\+[\w\+]*)(?:[^\w\+]|$)", s)
['fa+gq+hf+kg+is', 'gl+jh+ke+oj+kp']
```

Comment: this one is not working for the third row. it gives only fa+gq+hf+kg+is as output.. I want, fa+gq+hf+kg+is gl+jh+ke+oj+kp as output. can you help me in doing that?

Comment: @chisrtian this doesnt work with http://hostname.com/wqs/ck$st=+fasd/ . How can we make this work with this one as well

Comment: I tweaked it slightly to change the first `[\w\+]+` to `[\w\+]*`. Try that.

Answer (score 0):

If you change `[^\w\+ ]([\w\+ ]+\+[\w\+ ]+)(?:[^\w\+ ]|$)` to `[^\w\+ ]([\w\+ ]+\+[\w\+ ]*)(?:[^\w\+ ]|$)` it will match the second URL as well.

It will include the trailing '+', which isn't included in your desired output but does seem to meet the criteria you had mentioned, so this may take some modifying if you don't want any trailing '+'s.

Comment: @this one is not working for the third row. it gives only fa+gq+hf+kg+is as output.. I want, fa+gq+hf+kg+is gl+jh+ke+oj+kp as output. can you help me in doing that?

Answer (score 0):

After trying to use unsuccesfully [urlparse](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urlparse.html) it seems the best way to get the info you want is using regular expressions:

```
import urlparse
import re

urls = [
    "http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=fa+gw+hw+ek+ei/",
    "http://hostname.com/wqs/ck$st=fasd+/",
    "http://hostname.com/as/ck$st=fa+gq+hf+kg+is&sadfnlslkdfn&gl+jh+ke+oj+kp sfav"
]

for myurl in urls:
    parsed = urlparse.urlparse(myurl)

    print 'scheme  :', parsed.scheme
    print 'netloc  :', parsed.netloc
    print 'path    :', parsed.path
    print 'params  :', parsed.params
    print 'query   :', parsed.query
    print 'fragment:', parsed.fragment
    print 'username:', parsed.username
    print 'password:', parsed.password
    print 'hostname:', parsed.hostname, '(netloc in lower case)'
    print 'port    :', parsed.port

    print urlparse.parse_qs(parsed.query)

    print re.findall(r'([\w\+]+\+[\w\+]*)(?:[^\w\+]|$)', parsed.path)
    print '-' * 80
```

Comment: this doesnt work with hostname.com/wqs/ck$st=+fasd . How can we make this work with this one as well ? Can you please in this?